# Простой слайдер на чистом js

Tags: slider, javascript, pure_js

В розысках простой слайдер, который каждые X секунд перелистывает страницы слева в право (типо slide -а [здесь](http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/)). Ну плюс какие-нибудь функции, вроде getPage, setPage. Ну и конечно резиновость.

Казалось что найти такой слайдер легко. Однако по запросу slider в github 4 страницы подряд(больше не осилил) все слайдеры были на jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть по этой ссылке слайдер подойдет?
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
Тут несколько вариантов.
Вот тут пишут как им пользоваться: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=400

Comment: >  на чистом js

Comment: ну простите... я просто предложила...